# Should be a simple loop procedure in VBA

Tags: string, excel, vba

In Excel I have a column of words.  I believe you call words "strings" in the programming world.

Row by row, I need to take each word in the column and put single inverted commas around it.

For example, if the word in the cell is dog, I need to change it to 'dog'.

I am trying to write a macro to do this, but I am already running into problems with the very first part of the [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) code, which is just to import the column of words into [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) from the excel spreadsheet.

My code is below.  The Error message says "subscript out of range", but as you can see I have dimmed the array.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

```
    Sub putquotes()
    Dim sym(1 To 162) As String
    For i = 1 To 162
       sym(i) = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 1)
    Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: Not an VBA expert, but in most programming languages, arrays and strings start counting at 0. If that's the case in VBA too, then you need to do sym(i-1) = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i+1,1)

Comment: Examine in debug mode (when the code breaks at the error). Does `sym(i)` return Subscript out of range, or is it `Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 1)`? What's the value of `i` when it happens?

Comment: It's Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 1) that returns subscript out of range.  It seems to get through the first loop ok.  I think the bug occurs on the second loop.

Comment: I doubt you have a sheet called `sheet1`. The default first sheet is `Sheet1`

Comment: Yep, my bad.  Capitalizing the "S" in sheet was my problem.  However, I am very pleased with the answers below.  I think I will abandon what I was doing and read in the data using their suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue is your `sheet1` name which should probably be `Sheet1`

I would use something like this which will run on the first worksheet (see `Set ws = Sheets(1)`)

Note that the third sheet would be `Set ws = Sheets(3)`, or you could use `Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")` if you did have such a sheet

This code:

- will run independent of the sheet that is selected
- looks from the first to last used cell in column A (rather than hard-coding 162 rows)
- uses variant arrays rather than ranges for speed
- adds a double `''` to ensure the first is visible :)

  ```
  Sub PutQuotes()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim varList
  Dim rng1 As Range
  Dim lngCnt As Long
  Set ws = Sheets(1)
  Set rng1 = ws.Range(ws.[a1], ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
  varList = rng1.Value2

  For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(varList)
      If Len(varList(lngCnt, 1)) > 0 Then _
          varList(lngCnt, 1) = "''" & varList(lngCnt, 1) & "'"
  Next
  'dump updated array back over range
  rng1.Value2 = varList
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: This is great.  Many thanks.  Follow-up question: is it possible to go through the string in each cell letter by letter and delete the row if a certain character is found?  In my case, I need to delete rows where the string in the cell contains the following character:  ^

Comment: @ben thx :) This should really be asked as a new question. A quick way would be to use AutoFilter, either manually or with VBA

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a sheet named "Sheet1".  Either:

1. This code lives in a standard module in the workbook with the data and you've renamed the
   sheet, or
2. The code lives in another workbook and you haven't properly qualified your Worksheets property

I'm going to assume the latter.  When you use collection properties like Worksheets or Cells, Excel makes assumptions on who the parent is.  An unqualified Worksheets call in a standard module will assume

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets()
```

An unqualified Worksheets call in the ThisWorkbook module will assume

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets()
```

To check where the problem is, add this line to your code

```
Debug.Print Worksheets("Sheet1").Parent.Name
```

That will tell you which workbook Excel is using and may be different than you want.

To avoid bad guessing, it's best to fully qualify your references.  For instance, if you're opening the workbook with the data, it might look like this

```
Sub putquotes()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sym(1 To 162) As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Path\Name")

    For i = 1 To 162
        sym(i) = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 1)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Holding that wb reference is an easy way to qualify the reference.  If you're not opening a separate file in code, you can just qualify explicitly like

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Workbooks("Mybook.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

A better way to read cell values into an array is like this

```
Sub putquotes()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sym As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Path\Name")
    sym = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Resize(162, 1).Value

    For i = LBound(sym, 1) To UBound(sym, 1)
        Debug.Print "'" & sym(i, 1) & "'"
    Next i

End Sub
```

That will give you a two-dimensional-base-1 array, which you may not like, but it's faster than reading them in one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want something like this...

```
Public Sub DoQuotes()
    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim Result() As String
    iRow = 1

    Do While Not IsEmpty(Sheet1.Cells(iRow, 1))
        ReDim Preserve Result(iRow - 1)
        Result(iRow - 1) = "'" & Sheet1.Cells(iRow, 1) & "'"
    iRow = iRow + 1
    Loop

    For Each x In Result
        MsgBox (x)
    Next x

End Sub
```

However, bear in mind that Excel will treat the first quote as a text delimiter so it whilst the value in the array is 'something' it will look like something' in Excel.

Just a general aside point, try to avoid calls to Worksheets() instead use the strongly typed Sheet1 object - saves all sorts of future pain if the worksheets get renamed. You can see what the sheets are "really" called in the vba editor. It will say something like Sheet1(MyWorksheet)